# The photo or a photo? Which one is more appropriate for use?

Tags: articles

There's a sentence: **"A photo from the concert"**. And I am a little bit confused about the correct article there. I want to say that it was a specific photo, but at the same time, I understand, that there are many photos from the concert and this pic is one of them. So what's the right variant.
I will be grateful for your explanation!!

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time, when something new is introduced into the discourse, we use an indefinite article; thereafter, we use the definite article.

If *the first time you mention it*, you say "the photo from the concert", this sets up an expectation in the reader that they are supposed to know already  which photo you are talking about. If they have no reason to know which photo, they are likely to be confused.